# Python: Изменение режима для потока после его установки невозможно warnings.warn(str(err))

Tags: python, отладчик, pyglet

> C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs\wmf.py:838: UserWarning: [WinError -2147417850] Изменение режима для потока после его установки невозможно warnings.warn(str(err))

При обычном запуске ошибок нет, но если запустить debugger (работаю в pycharm) то он выдает ошибку выше. Подскажите в чём проблема и насколько это критично, если debugger - пишет ошибку, а при запуске программы всё ок. Вот код:

```
import pyglet

sound = pyglet.media.load("Ваш_Файл.wav")
sound.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Вот это наверное в самом низу надо поставить pyglet.app.run()

Comment: @Александр, ```pyglet.app.run() ``` и так является последней строчкой функции  ```voice```